# What tag should be used to contain multiple th elements

Tags: html, jsx

I'm getting `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag` when I do the following.

```
<tr>
    { R.repeat((
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Last</th>
    ), 3) }                    
</tr>
```

What should the pairs of th tags be wrapped in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the elements in a `Fragment` so you will no longer get that issue. You can check out the [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
<tr>
    { R.repeat((
        <React.Fragment>
          <th>First</th>
          <th>Last</th>
        </React.Fragment>
    ), 3) }                    
</tr>
```

Alternate Syntax

```
<tr>
    { R.repeat((
        <>
          <th>First</th>
          <th>Last</th>
        </>
    ), 3) }                    
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternative to the approach I was taking, but would still be curious if there are other ways...

```
<tr>
    { R.repeat((
        R.map((n) => (<th key={ n }>{ n }</th>), ['Port', 'Reports'])
    ), 3)}
</tr>
```

Comment: This looks like a solid answer!